# ¿Cómo convierto una lista en diccionario?

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

Quiero escribir una función que genere un diccionario donde las claves son los números del 1 al 15 (ambos incluidos) y los valores son el cuadrado de las claves.

Ejemplo:

```
{
  1 : 1,
  2 : 4,
  3 : 9,
  ...
}
```

Al principio quise hacerlo así, pero no entiendo por qué me arroja el "último valor del diccionario":

```
  rango = range(1,16)
  rango_lista = list(rango)

  for i in rango_lista:
      dicc = {i : i**2}
        
  print(dicc)
  {15: 225}
```

Después intenté hacer 2 listas:

- Una con los valores [1,2...15]
- y otra con los valores cuadrados [1,4...225]

Pero también tengo problemas: realizo un ciclo 'for' para calcular los cuadrados, pero no puedo convertirlos en lista:

```
  for n in rango_lista:
      print(n**2)

 1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
100
121
144
169
196
225

225


#Pero no sé como convertir eso en una lista:
         
  rango_lista_2
  for n in rango_lista:
     rango_lista_2 = [n**2]
        
  rango_lista_2
  [225]
```

En conclusión:

- ¿Cómo puedo resolver el ejercicio? ¿En qué estoy fallando?
- ¿Se puede realizar de las 2 formas que planteé?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Pero no entiendo porque me arroja el "último valor del diccionario":*

```
  for i in rango_lista:
      dicc = {i : i**2}
        
  print(dicc)
  {15: 225}
```

La razón es que en cada iteración reemplazas `dicc` con un nuevo diccionario.

Si *quieres* agregar una llave-valor al diccionario, se hace asi:

```
  dicc = {}
  for i in rango_lista:
      dicc[i] = i**2
```

La segunda solución que intentaste tiene el mismo problema: en cada iteración reemplazas la lista por una nueva lista. La solución es la misma:

```
  rango_lista_2 = []
  for n in rango_lista:
     rango_lista_2.append(n**2)
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema te está pasando porque en cada ciclo del bucle creas un nuevo diccionario.
Prueba a crearlo fuera del bucle y a rellenarlo dentro:

```
dicc = {}
for i in rango_lista:
    dicc[i] = i**2
```

Tu segundo problema con las listas, aunque con la solución anterior ya no lo necesitarías puedes resolverlo así:

```
lista_cuadrados = []
for n in rango_lista:
      lista_cuadrados.append(n**2)
```

O lo que sería lo mismo:

```
lista_cuadrados = [n**2 for n in rango_lista]
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu idea de hacer `dicc = {i : i**2}` es buena. Como han comentado en las otras respuestas, esto está creando un diccionario de nuevo en cada ocasión.

Para seguir con la misma lógica, podrías definir el diccionario dinámicamente, por ejemplo con:

```
def genera_dicc(num_elems=15):
    rango = range(1, num_elems + 1)
    return {k: k**2 for k in rango}
```

Veámoslo en acción:

```
>>> genera_dicc(2)
{1: 1, 2: 4}
>>> genera_dicc(5)
{1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25}
```